# Ubuntu 16.04—Gnome session runs Unity?

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, lightdm

Some time back I installed `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` in Ubuntu 16.04 (possibly 14.04, since upgraded?) and it used to work fine. Now if I choose that session at the lightdm greeter I get a desktop which I think is actually Unity (`XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=unity`), although there is no launcher or top panel and windows don’t have widgets. If I run `gnome-shell --replace` in a terminal the Unity launcher and top panel appear. I’ve tried purging the package and reinstalling it, but nothing changes (in fact very little seems to be removed or reinstalled).

`/usr/share/xsessions` contains a `gnome.desktop` with `Exec=gnome-session --session=gnome` which sounds right.

**Edit:** I tried removing most/all of the contents `~/.config/autostart` and then `gnome-shell --replace` *does* start gnome. Still don’t understand why the session starts Unity though. `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` still says `unity`.

As a fresh install, 16.04 has been OK, but as an upgrade it seems very, very buggy.

**Edit 2:** After installing `budgie-desktop` from the budgie-remix PPA I get the same result. I guess the common denominator is Gnome.

**Edit 3:** Guest logins show the same behaviour—Unity, xfce and fluxbox work fine; Gnome and budgie don’t. This seems to rule out another commonly offered solution: deleting ~/.config or ~/.cache.

What is going on here?